# How can I update a Site Column with the content of an array with javascript CSOM?

Tags: javascript, site-column, csom

I'm relative new to Sharepoint 2013, I'm trying to update the content of a Site column with the content of an array, I can retrieve and visualize the content of my site column, the user is able to change and save the necessary part and the changes are saved into an array, now I have to update the content of the site column with the content of the array, but for some kind of reasons I can't accomplish that, any suggestion/example? This is my code so far to retrieve, visualize the site column and store the mofication into my array.

```
<body>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="optSelect()">
            <option value="EngineType_Cylinders">EngineType_Cylinders</option>
            <option value="EngineType_EngineCycle">EngineType_EngineCycle</option>
            <option value="EngineType_EngineFamily">EngineType_EngineFamily</option>
            <option value="EngineType_Euro">EngineType_Euro</option>
            <option value="EngineType_FamilyEvolution">EngineType_FamilyEvolution</option>
            <option value="EngineType_GasEmissionLevel">EngineType_GasEmissionLevel</option>
            <option value="EngineType_Power">EngineType_Power</option>
            <option value="EngineType_PowerSupply">EngineType_PowerSupply</option>
            <option value="EngineType_Use">EngineType_Use</option>
        </select><br />

        <textarea id="textareadisplay" rows="25" cols="23"></textarea><br />
        <input type ="button" value="Update values" onclick="addItemsToColumns()" />
    </body>
```

My Javascript

```
$(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
       var select = document.getElementById('dropdown').value;
        console.log(select);
        getSiteColumns(select);

    }), 'SP.js');
});

var fieldChoice;
var choices;
var addFields = [];
var slc;
var clientContext;

function optSelect() {
    slc = document.getElementById('dropdown').value;
    getSiteColumns(slc);
}

function getSiteColumns(selection) {
   clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {

        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        fieldChoice = clientContext.castTo(web.get_availableFields().getByTitle(selection), SP.FieldChoice);

        clientContext.load(this.fieldChoice);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
    }
}

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
    choices = fieldChoice.get_choices();
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textareadisplay");
    textarea.value = choices.join("\n");

}

function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function addItemsToColumns() {
    clientC = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var arrayForUpdate = $('#textareadisplay').val().split('\n');
    fieldChoice.set_item(, arrayForUpdate);
    fieldChoice.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { }, function () { });


}

function OnUpdateSuccess(sender, args) {
    var newchoices = fieldChoice.get_choices();

}
```

My problem is on the function addItemsToColumns() please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, un collega italiano! Se sei in zona Milano e sei interessato, la mia società sta cercando un dev sharepoint.

Comment: @MdMazzotti grande! grazie! Lasciami la tua mail ti che ti contatto ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question properly, you would like to update field of `SP.FieldChoice` type, in particular set choice values.

If so,then the following example demonstrates to update `SP.FieldChoice` using SharePoint JSOM API:

```
function updateFieldChoice(fieldTitle,choiceValues,success,failure) {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var fieldChoice = ctx.castTo(web.get_availableFields().getByTitle(fieldTitle), SP.FieldChoice);
    fieldChoice.set_choices(choiceValues);
    fieldChoice.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function(){
            success(fieldChoice)
         },
         failure);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var choiceValues = ["Low", "Normal", "Critical"];

updateFieldChoice('RequestStatus',choiceValues,
    function(field){
       console.log('Choice field has been updated'); 
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

> In your case please replace the line:
>
> ```
> var choiceValues = ["Low", "Normal", "Critical"];
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> var arrayForUpdate = $('#textareadisplay').val().split('\n');
> ```

**Result**

[image]